# Find the sum of alphabetical characters in a string

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get the sum of all selected values from an array. If a user searches for a word it should return a sum for the searched word. Example below.

```
$chars = array(1 => 'a', 2 => 'b', 3 => 'c'); // Chars start from a-z
$data = 'aac'; // for example

foreach ($chars as $results) {
    if (strpos($results, $data) !== false) {
         $search = array_search($results, $chars);
    }
}
```

If search is `"aac"` then the results should be `1 + 1 + 3 = 5`.

I have tried the `array_keys()` function and it did not work.

Comment: $search is over written each time.

Comment: I tried changing that Jason, it now returns sum as zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save having to search the array for the value of the character, instead use `array_flip()` to make it an array indexed by the character itself.  Then just add the items up (using `??` in case the item doesn't exist to add 0)...

```
$sum = 0;
$chars = array_flip($chars);
foreach (str_split($data) as $char) {
    $sum += $chars[$char] ?? 0; 
}
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to create a character array, then [accumulate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) [lowercase alphabetical characters only](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-lower.php) into a sum. Use [`ord`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) to get an ASCII code per letter instead of [hardcoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) a literal array (the array would only be useful if you want arbitrary weights per character; see other answers).

```
<?php
$data = "aac";

$result = array_reduce(str_split($data), function ($a, $e) {    
    return $a + (ctype_lower($e) ? ord($e) - 96 : 0);
}, 0);

echo $result; // => 5
```

If you wish to ignore case and treat `"A"` as `"a"`, you can use [`strtolower`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php).

```
<?php
$data = "aAc";

$result = array_reduce(str_split(strtolower($data)), function ($a, $e) {    
    return $a + (ctype_lower($e) ? ord($e) - 96 : 0);
}, 0);

echo $result; // => 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split your `$data` into an array and loop over every character in the string. Search for the string in the array, and if it exists, then add the index you get from `array_search()` to a `$sum` variable.

```
$sum = 0;
foreach (str_split($data) as $char) {
    if (($index = array_search($char, $chars)) !== false) {
        $sum += $index;
    }
}
echo $sum;
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/XCK8r